# Creating Quadtree/Space Filling Curve Index atop GeoTiFF

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, spatial-index, quadtree

I'm a complete beginner in GeoTiFF manipulation. I'd like to get some help in possible Java/Python/Scala project which performs spatial indexing (Quadtree, Space Filling Curves) atop given image(s). I intend to store these images in a database along with the spatial indexes calculated for subsequent retrieval. Would be glad if I could get a head start. I already became aware of [GeoTools](https://geotools.org/), [Apache Commons Imaging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/) like libraries. At the moment I'm trying to get familiar with the libraries. Would like community's help in finding more libraries/ tools projects.

Comment: are you planning to index the contents of the image or it's position?

Comment: hi @IanTurton, I intend to index the position (lat, long).